# Cross product simplifying

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\iint z \, dS$  where $S$ is the upper hemisphere of radius $2.$

I worked out $r_x = \langle -2\sin(x)\sin(y),2\cos(x)\sin(y),0\rangle$ and $r_y = \langle 2\cos(x)\cos(y),2\sin(x)\cos(y),-2\sin(y)\rangle$ .

Now taking the cross product of this then taking the magnitude of the cross product will take a very long time so is there an easier way of doing this considering they havent given any point. I read somewhere that

$$\left \| \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\times \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \right \| = \left \| \frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \right \|\left \| \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \right \|$$

Is this true under any circumstance?

Comment: generally $\vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \| A \| \| B \| \sin \theta \hat{n}$ where $\hat{n}$ is a unit-vector given by the right hand rule. So, $\| \vec{A} \times \vec{B} \| = \| A \| \| B \| $ given $\sin \theta =1$ which requires $\theta = \pi/2$. Is the dot-product between your vectors zero?

Comment: However, taking that cross product should not be a big deal to you if you are taking the course where this is asked. That is pretty routine and you ought to be able to just do it without much thinking.